# Must be one of: Service.START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY, Service.START_STICKY, Service.START_NOT_STICKY, Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT

Tags: android, android-studio, android-service

When I have:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) { 
    try { 
        player.start(); 
        isRunning = true; 
    } 
    catch(Exception e) { 
        isRunning = false; 
        player.stop(); 
    } 

    return 1;
}
```

I get the following "error" for `return 1`:

> Must be one of: Service.START_STICKY_COMPATIBILITY, Service.START_STICKY, Service.START_NOT_STICKY, Service.START_REDELIVER_INTENT

How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you meant to return [START_STICKY](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#START_STICKY), which is of type *int* equal to `1`, from [onStartCommand(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html#onStartCommand(android.content.Intent,%20int,%20int)), you **did nothing wrong**. This is your *IDE* that prompts it.

You can ignore the warning. In case of absence of other errors, your code will compile and run successfully.

If the warning is annoying, `return START_STICKY` instead.